# iPhone link to map directions using string "current location" not lat and lng for saddr

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location

I know there are numerous questions about how to construct a sharedApplication link to the maps app specifying the start and end address with coordinates. I've got that working no problem.

Has anyone found a way to link with a source address generically specified as "current location".

I ask because the scenario I'm working on having Core Location or a UIMapView would only be necessary in order to determine the user location prior to handing off to the map app where the user locating would seem to just happen again.

I've tried throwing UTF8'd "Current Location" and "[Current Location]" into the saddr parameter which amusingly starts from Current Montana. I've also tried simply excluding the saddr param.

I know this is often tread territory but this particular situation wasn't covered by anything I found searching here or on mapki. Before I add the core location code I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a more limited way to tackle this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post is quite old, but recently I had to face a similar issue and I developed a solution.

Using "Current Location" (properly escaped) as source address works perfectly.
The downside is that "Current Location" is valid for English language only. If your iPhone is set to use another language, you need to know the exact translation that Apple chose for that particular language.

I wrote a class that can provide the exact translation for "Current Location" in any supported language. You can read [my blog post](http://www.martip.net/blog/localized-current-location-string-for-iphone-apps) about this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 "current location" (or the correct translation) is fine if you escape the space, a la **current%20location**. It's actually Google's translation choice that you need to know.

Comment: Thanks martip!

Matthew are you sure it's 'Google's Translation' to me it would make more sense if it was the iOS's translation – i.e. whatever the user sees.

Comment: Note that this method doesn't work on iPad (lat,lng still does though...)

Comment: @William: Thanks, I had not tried the trick on the iPad. Sadly I can now confirm that it doesn't work on the iPad.